# want to convert negative number to positive

Tags: sql-server

I have a below query which I have used this in a procedure and want to convert one number into positive as right now it is negative.

```
 UPDATE SHIPMENT
        SET TOTAL_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT = (
          CASE
            WHEN V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT > v_diff_cost
            THEN V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT - v_diff_cost
            ELSE v_diff_cost       - V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT
          END)
        WHERE SHIPMENT_GID = v_shipment_id;
        COMMIT;
```

in this query v_diff_cost value is negative so while performing `( V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT - v_diff_cost)` action it is adding both the values so if I will convert `v_diff_cost` value to positive then while subtracting it will give me the right result.

Suppose `V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT` value is 33 and `v_diff_cost value` is -10 then in this case it should perform the action as `33-10 = 23` but it is doing as `33-(-10)= 43` and this should not happen.

kindly help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use <kbd>[ABS()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189800.aspx)</kbd> function,

> MSDN : A mathematical function that returns the absolute (positive) value of the specified numeric expression.

```
UPDATE SHIPMENT
    SET TOTAL_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT = (
      CASE
        WHEN V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT > v_diff_cost
        THEN V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT - ABS(v_diff_cost)
        ELSE ABS(v_diff_cost)       - V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT
      END)
    WHERE SHIPMENT_GID = v_shipment_id;
    COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
UPDATE SHIPMENT
        SET TOTAL_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT = (
          CASE
            WHEN V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT > v_diff_cost
            THEN V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT - abs(v_diff_cost)
            ELSE v_diff_cost       - abs(V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT)
          END)
        WHERE SHIPMENT_GID = v_shipment_id;
        COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE SHIPMENT
SET TOTAL_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT = ABS(V_SHIP_UNIT_COUNT - ABS(v_diff_cost)) 
WHERE SHIPMENT_GID = v_shipment_id;
```